# Code library to find resolution of screen of android or ios phone

Tags: android, ios

Is there any C++ code or library to get screen resolution in iOS and Android phones and tablets. So that I can size my app as per device

Comment: Of course its possible to get the screen resolution, but your question isn't clear enough about what your exact requirements are. For example you imply you are developing a cross-platform app in C++, but you only imply that, you aren't clear what the restrictions or limitations or requirements of getting the screen resolution are to match your particular needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An overly broad answer to an overly broad question.

On iOS you can use [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size, but you really shouldn't.

You should create separate layouts for iPhone and iPad in interface builder, probably as storyboards.  Having done that and correctly configured the Info.plist file, the correct storyboard will automatically be selected based on the current device.  Make sure to use autolayout or properly set up your autoresizingMask to account for slight variations in screen size (iPhone 4 vs. iPhone 5) and you're good to go.

You also won't (shouldn't) be doing much interface building for either platform in C++.  On iPhone your interface code will be in Objective-C (or C# with appropriate dev kits)  On Android it's going to be in Java.

Take a look around for tutorials on development for both platforms and you should get a better idea of the expected norms/best practices.